# Improving observation, attention to detail in mental imagery

Tags: cognitive-psychology, attention, visualization

Once in a while I remember the whole "use mental imagery to remember things" thing and start looking for information about it (never actually tried to turn it into a habit...).

It doesn't take long for me to find some "article" or another stating that improving our attention to detail, the vividness of our mental imagery and our observation skills will make these techniques working even better (makes sense, I guess).

... And then comes the training. Games such as Kim's game are offered, but I can't find a shred of evidence that any of these things (skills?) can improve (nothing that shows evidence that they can't be improved either).

Kim's game, for example, is used in the U.S. army  training (at least according to Wikipedia), but  I can't find any research done into that...

So, is there any basis to Kim's game, or any other game claiming to improve observation skills, attention to detail and the vividness of our imagination?

Putting meditation (which is well known for being very good for many things) aside, I can't find anything (maybe I'm not even looking for the right things. I wouldn't know much in the way of scientific in this field)